# Opening TCP port 443 to specific domains?

Tags: macos, monterey, firewall

I am trying to work remotely with a healthcare professional through Doxy.me, a URL that that they prefer for client calls (e.g., rather than Zoom, etc.). When I attempt to meet with them, everything is fine until we start to connect for a call--at that point, the call ends automatically. We're still able to chat via text in the browser but can't connect for video calls.

According to [Doxy.me's troubleshooting](https://help.doxy.me/en/articles/95887-configure-network-settings), the site requires opening TCP port 443 to several domains, including:

```
doxy.me
*.doxy.me
*.opentok.com 
*.tokbox.com
*.pubnub.com
pndsn.com
limnu.com 
*.limnu.com 
growthbook.io
*.growthbook.io
*.cloudflare.net intercom.io 
*.intercom.io
segment.com
*.segment.com
dokbot.io
*.dokbot.io
```

My problem is, I do not know how to open the firewall on macOS Monterey to whitelist those domains. Is this possible? Or is it more likely an issue with the router and not the OS?

Note: Doxy's page also links to an online tool for checking whether port 443 is open or not, and when I try that tool the results say it's closed (?)

Comment: Edit: Doxy's page also links to an online tool for checking whether port 443 is open or not, and when i try that tool the results say it's closed (?).

Comment: Do you have the firewall enabled on your Mac?  Is it the built-in one (pf) or a 3rd party firewall?

Comment: Just using the built-in firewall; i thought it was prudent to have it set to "on" and blocking all incoming connections, so that's how i have it. I thought that if your machine *initiates* a connection, then that would override blocking incoming connections, so on balance this was the safer setup.

Comment: Disable it and see if it works.  This will rule out whether it's your Mac or a network firewall.

Comment: This isn't an answer, just some info. 443 is the port that inbound web traffic hit's when visiting a site over https. So, if you go to https://google.com, then you're visiting google over port 443. MOST internet service providers block INCOMING web traffic to ports 80 and 443 to keep you from opening a hosting company in your basement. Any test you run against a home or non-commercial connection to port 443 will fail. I do not think this is your issue with Doxy.